# Using react-scroll (Link) while using react-boostrap Nav.Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, smooth-scrolling

I was able to set up responsive navbar using react-bootstrap, but when I tried using Link from react-scroll withing Nav.Link

```
<Nav.Link href='projects'>
  <Link 
     activeClass='active'
     to='homepage'
     spy={true}
     smooth={true}
     offset={-70}
     duration= {500}
  >
  Projects
  </Link>
</Nav.Link>
```

I would get an error on the browser stating `<a> cannot appear as a descendant of a <a>`. I tried to change Nav.Link to Nav.Item and change styles of link accordingly, but once I remover Nav.Link the collapseOnSelect feature stops working in my Navbar for mobile.

```
import React from 'react';
import Scroll from 'react-scroll';

import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

import { ReactComponent as GithubIcon } from '../../assets/github.svg';
import { ReactComponent as TwitterIcon } from '../../assets/twitter.svg';

class Header extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='header' style={{ fontFamily: 'Fira Code, monospace' }}>
        <Navbar className='shadow-lg' style={{ backgroundColor: '#2C3E50' }} collapseOnSelect expand="lg" fixed="top">
          <Navbar.Brand onSelect={() => Scroll.scrollTo('Homepage', {
            smooth: true,
                offset: -70,
                duration: 500
          })}>
            Name
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav'/>
          <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
            <Nav className='mr-auto'>
              <Nav.Link onSelect={() => Scroll.scrollTo('projects', {
                smooth: true,
                offset: -70,
                duration: 500
              })}>
                Projects
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link onSelect={() => Scroll.scrollTo('contact', {
                smooth: true,
                offset: -70,
                duration: 500
              })}>
                Contact
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Nav className='ml-auto'>
              <Nav.Link
                href='https://github.com/jgil-r'
                target='_blank'
                rel='noopener noreferrer'
                style={{
                  paddingLeft: '.5rem',
                  paddingRight: '.5rem'
                }}
              >
                <GithubIcon />
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link
                href='https://twitter.com/chuygil7273'
                target='_blank'
                rel='noopener noreferrer'
                style={{
                  paddingLeft: '.5rem',
                  paddingRight: '.5rem'
                }}
              >
                <TwitterIcon />
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

```
import React from 'react';

import './projects.styles.scss';

const Projects = () => (
  <div className='projects-container' id='projects'>
    <h1>Projects</h1>
  </div>
);

export default Projects;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since both Nav.Link and Link are components that render to `<a>` you can't include a Link inside of a Nav.Link.

You can use the `onSelect` property on the Nav.Link to add scrolling effects (and remove the Link from react-scroll) or set the Nav.Link `as` property to `div`.

```js
import Scroll from 'react-scroll';

// ...
<Nav.Link
onSelect={() => Scroll.scrollTo('homepage', {
    smooth: true,
    offset: -70,
    duration: 500,
})}
>

</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: I am still unable to get the scroll animation set up. I have edited my header file up top with changes.

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late but hopefully someone else struggling on this can find this helpful

For me, `Scroll.ScrollTo` wasn't working

Instead, try importing `scroller` and use the scrollTo like this

```
import { scroller } from "react-scroll";
//...
<Nav.Link
onClick={() => scroller.scrollTo('homepage', {
    smooth: true,
    offset: -70,
    duration: 500,
})}
>

</Nav.Link>
```

Note: I am also using onClick instead of onSelect

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
import { Link } from "react-scroll";
//...
<Nav className="mr-auto">
       <li className="nav-item">
          <Link
              href="#home"
              to="home"
              activeClass="active"
              className="nav-link"
              spy={true}
              smooth={true}
              offset={-70}
              duration={500}
              >
               Home
              </Link>
       </li>
</Nav>
```